# kubectl - get names of pods with specific label

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to get the podname from the pod json using the command which is returning the error

```
kgp -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata[?(@.labels.module=='ddvv-script')].name}"
```

Error

```
 is not array or slice and cannot be filtered. Printing more information for debugging the template:
        template was:
                {.items[*].metadata[?(@.labels.module=='ddvv-script')].name}
        object given to jsonpath engine was:
```

Sample file

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "Pod",
            "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": "2020-09-18T17:42:50Z",
                "generateName": "ddvv-script-6b784db6bd-",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "my-configs",
                    "lf.module": "ddvv-script",
                    "module": "ddvv-script",
                    "pod-template-hash": "6b784db6bd",
                    "release": "config"
                },
                "name": "ddvv-script-6b784db6bd-rjtgh",
```

What is wrong with this command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below command. It gets podname of pods which has label `module=ddvv-script`

```
kubectl get pods --selector=module=ddvv-script --output=jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kgp -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata[?(@.labels.module=='ddvv-script')].name}"
```

should be

```
kgp -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.labels.module=='ddvv-script')].metadata.name}"
```